# What are the JRE version requirements of JWrapper?

Tags: java, jwrapper

I'm trying to get my online JWrapper installers to use the system JRE, however they always end up downloading a JRE resulting in tens of GB a day of download traffic. In the log I see the following log messages:

```
+161      [Extractor] Checking JRE version requirements: 0 vs required 6
+0        [JRESearch] JRE does not exist or does not have unpack200
+0        [JREDownload] Failed to pick up any existing system JRE, will download
```

So, what are the six JRE version requirements and is it possible to supply a unpack200 implementation for the installer to use?

Comment: six requirements? you mean JRE version 6?

Comment: Hi Christopher, the JRE just needs to exist and have an unpack200 executable which is something a standard JRE would have.  Are you sure these systems do have a JRE installed?  If so what OS are they and what is the folder you expect them to pick it up from?

Comment: In this case it's Ubuntu, but the check seems to be failing on many, possibly all systems. unpack200 is installed in /usr/bin/unpack200. Would you be able to post some more details of the check or ideally some code for the check and I'll run it the affected systems?

Comment: It does 'which java' then follows the links, you should see an entry like "[JRESearch] Looking at JRE xxx" before these, can you post that and look at the folder then run 'java -version' from it and post the output?